# jquery position() seems not perfect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a web application and I have some feature where the user can drag some text in the page to their desired position and if they click save button, the next page shows the same text at the position they dropped. It is working but the position is not perfect, somewhat slightly changes from the original one.

I implemented such feature in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/AmEeH/

You can see the **#text-preview** which is the original text where you can drag it to the desired position. After you dropped, I want to move **#ttext-preview** to the same position where **#text-preview** is dropped. But the **#ttext-preview** position is not changing.

I just want to know why the position slightly changes from the original text dropped position in my web application. I try to show the problem in the jsfiddle, but the jsfiddle itself is not working ( I can't change the css **top and left** property of **#ttext-preview** dynamically through jquery ).

Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure this is not it, but do you mean the slight shift in the jsfiddle due to the removal of the border after dropping the element?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing some slight shift in the text position from the originally dropped position. Is that causing due to the hover border? But I need that border.

Comment: I added an answer about the border issue. Not sure if that is the problem you're having. Check out the fiddle I create to show the version without the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the border that you use during the dragging. When you change that into a background color it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qvS2t/

If you want to keep using the border I would add some extra padding on the non-hovering tekst and replace that with the border when the hover is active. Here's a jsfiddle that shows how to  do this: http://jsfiddle.net/jdCAx/

Comment: I've tried adding 3px to top and left. But still it is different. Could you show me the working example in jsfiddle? Thanks!

Comment: I changed my answer and added a second jsfiddle to show you how to do easily solve this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help @koenp but look at this now http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/jdCAx/2/ Can you see the difference?

Comment: Ok, maybe this one does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/jdCAx/3/. It seems to have a slight difference now and then. Not sure though...

Answer (score 0):

1. Initially .position() gets the coordinates RELATIVE to the parent !
2. Another thing might be the border/margin/padding-issue, have a lot over here http://api.jquery.com/position/ ! You are using a strange hover-border, which may irretate the position thing, as the element is not on 0,0 anymore when you hover over it

Comment: So what mistake I've done, which shows the text in somewhat different position from the originally dropped position?

Comment: But I need that hover border which is good to show that the text is draggable.

Comment: @rnk your problem is the BORDER which comes up after hovering over the element ! try to make the border INSIDE of the div or working around this via a div in div solution.

Comment: Please check out this http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/jdCAx/2/ You can see the difference clearly